# How to use jquery Backstretch in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to use backstretch in asp.net MVC. I included script files in my view page after when I run my program the image is not shown in the browser.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>

<script>
$.backstretch([ "Images/img1.jpg",
                "Images/img2.jpg],
                {
                   fade:750,
                   duration:10000
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just syntax error. You don't have a closing quotation mark for `img2.jpg`.
It should be

```
$.backstretch([ "Images/img1.jpg",
                "Images/img2.jpg"],
                {
                   fade:750,
                   duration:10000
                });
```

Make use of developer tools in a browser (example: In Google Chrome `F12` will take you to dev tools) to identify javascript errors. Switch to `console` tab to see the errors. and you can click on the link on the right hand side to locate the error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Prashanth I modified the code as you told but still it did'nt work and no errors showing on the console.

Comment: @ThamizhArasan Hmmm.... once the code is modified it actually is working. I would suggest you to check the image paths.